# Effects of totally sleeping vs. just closing your eyes

Tags: sleep

Will totally sleeping (closed eyes, unconscious) have the same effect **physically** with just lying in bed and just closing your eyes even if you're still conscious?

Comment: This isn't a question about _worldbuilding_, rather a question about the biology of a real, existing creature on modern Earth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems off-topic, more appropriate for a biology type of site. Still, it is very easy for me to answer...

I have sleeping problems, so I can tell you from personal experience that just lying down with your eyes closed but remaining conscious does *not* provide the same physical effect as full sleep.

I think part of the reason for this is that certain portions of the brain need to be shut down in order to properly rejuvenate themselves from the sleep.

This is not to say that merely lying down with eyes closed is not beneficial. On the contrary; resting *is* beneficial even if it is not full sleep. It's just not the same as the full sleep.

Sorry for the highly circumstantial evidence, but that's all that was required for this question.

You might want to try editing your question if this is not all you were looking for, also to make it fit better with the world-building topic.

Answer (score 0):

We sleep to store memories and heal muscle tissue and wounds.

Simply laying down with your eyes closed probably would help to regenerate faster but won't be as effective as entering sleep metabolism, and surely you wouldn't be able to transform memories in permanent as efficiently without proper sleep.

Between having your eyes closed has almost nothing to do with sleeping , many animals and even some people sleep with eyes open.

The reason we close them is because they waste energy while we don't need them.

Comment: That we sleep to forge long-term memories is only a theory, it has not been proven in an way and could well be incorrect or incomplete. You should specify that.

Comment: even gravity is a theory, I don't see people specifying it before telling others  to not  jump from a bridge...

Comment: You are using two different meanings of the word "theroy" here. That if someone jumps from a bridge they fall has been proven. That sleep (and dreams) serve to create long-term memories, or forget "useless" memories, or "train" ourselves for stressful situations (as well as many other theories) have not been proven and might well be **dis**proven in the future